# Facing issue in connecting ReactJS to SpringBoot in production server hosting in same tomcat server

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, production

I have a production server having tomcat server in sentora zpanel.
I have created two war files for ReactJS production build files and SpringBoot war files.
I have assigned https domain name to ReactJS war file and connecting SpringBoot war file with http api.
In localhost it is working fine but in production it is not working. I have resolved cors issue in localhost.

How to connect ReactJS to Springboot api, and need to resolve production issues while connecting each other

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of all relevant code, errors, and configs